# OpenGL ES 2.0 screen scroll: translate vs. setLookatM

Tags: java, android, performance, matrix, opengl-es

For a 3D-world with only about 500 separate objects with only about 20 triangles to draw per object, which would be faster to simulate scrolling in the x-y plane: translating all objects' x and y OR changing setLookAtM parameters for every drawn frame?

(Assume all objects could be displayed on the screen every frame, and most of them are like small flat (thin) boxes.)

I guess the question boils down to "Which takes less time?":

1. Performing (1,000) float additions (1000 additions = 500 objects x 2 float additions [x+x_offset & y+y_offset] for translation. I have to update x and y using translateM for all objects every frame anyway whether scrolling is performed or not.)

or

1. One call to change setLookAtM parameters.

Or is there a better (faster) way to simulate scrolling with OpenGl ES 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by translating every object. Every object should be translated anyway according to its position - meaning, each object has a defined x/y, and when you draw it you do something as follows:

```
glPushMatrix()
glTranslate(position.x, position.y);

// Draw object

glPopMatrix()
```

Now, you want to make sure your camera is always centered at a certain position which moves. For example, let's say you're always centered at the player's position which can move around.

```
glLoadIdentity()
glTranslate(-playerPosition.x, -playerPosition.y);

for each drawable object:
  if (isObjectWithinCamerasView(object)) // no need to draw objects outside of the viewport
    object.draw()
```

The method isObjectWithCamerasView should check how far the object's position is from the player's position (since if it's too far, it will be outside of the camera and therefore there's no need to draw it).

No need to alter the look-at matrix, all you need is one global translation before you individually translate each object according to its actual position.